# SQL Query - Number Of Offers question on Interviewbit

Tags: mysql

Given 2 tables ‘Students’ and ‘Jobs’, write an SQL query to find for every student the number of offers they got in the month of November. The output should contain 1 column by the name ‘Job_Offers’ which should contain the number of jobs received by each of the student in the month of November. Also it should be sorted by the Id of the students.

```
Table:Students
Id: INT (PK)
Name: Varchar

Table: Jobs
Id: INT
Date: DATE
Salary: INT
```

Id of this table and Id of Students table are identical

The output should contain one column `Job_Offers`.

My code is producing the wrong output

```
SELECT COUNT(Jobs.Id) AS Job_Offers 
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN Jobs ON Students.Id = Jobs.Id
WHERE MONTH(Jobs.Date) = 11
GROUP BY Students.Id
ORDER BY Students.Id
```

The solution is

```
SELECT COUNT(Jobs.Id) AS Job_Offers 
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN Jobs ON Students.Id = Jobs.Id 
               AND MONTH(Jobs.Date) = 11
GROUP BY Students.Id
ORDER BY Students.Id
```

Why can't we use `WHERE` here and why `COUNT(*)` is also not working?

Thank you

Comment: Please publish sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on this line "write an SQL query to find for every student the number of offers they got in the month of November". Result should be for every student.

```
SELECT COUNT(Jobs.Id) AS Job_Offers 
FROM Students  
LEFT JOIN Jobs ON Students.Id = Jobs.Id  
WHERE MONTH(Jobs.Date) = 11  
GROUP BY Students.Id  
ORDER BY Students.Id;
```

This query will remove tuples which have NULL Date After LEFT JOIN, so only students will be shown in result who has at least a job offer in November.

```
SELECT COUNT(Jobs.Id) AS Job_Offers  
FROM Students  
LEFT JOIN Jobs ON Students.Id = Jobs.Id AND MONTH(Jobs.Date) = 11  
GROUP BY Students.Id  
ORDER BY Students.Id;
```

However in this query there will be students in result who has at least a job offer and no job offer in November.